# Sequelize not updating a row in table

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for the first time. I have a table called `feed` in my DB, with columns `ID`, `caption`, and `url`. In my controller I have a simple function where I am updating a row in a table:

```
router.patch('/:id', 
    requireAuth, 
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        let { id } = req.params;
        const item =  await FeedItem.update({ ...req.body }, {
            where: {
              id: id
            }
        });
        if (item === null) {
            return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Feed not found' });
        }
        res.send(item);
});
```

I am sending json body that looks like this:

```
{
    "caption": "NewTest",
    "url": "Newtest.jpg"
}
```

I see that data is sent correctly in the console, but when I post to the endpoint with an id of 2, I get as a response:

```
[
    1
]
```

I can also see in the DB, that the row has not been updated.
What am I doing wrong here, how can I updated a row in the table and return the new updated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FeedItem.update` method returns count of affected rows. That is why you are getting `1`. If you need to have `FeedItem` instance itself you can retrieve it first and update the instance:

```
let feedItem = await FeedItem.findById(id);
if (!feedItem) {
   return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Feed not found' });
}
feedItem = await feedItem.updateAttributes(req.body);

return res.send(feedItem);
```

Comment: but, then I wonder why the row wasn't updated when I was running updated myself

Comment: Looks like everything is ok with your code, it has to update the record in DB